# Why is there a question mark at the end of the string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Please help me to figure out why there is a question mark at my string output. I have been working on this simple reverse a string practice. My code can do it correctly. Then I try to store the reversed string into an array and then convert this array to a string. So here is something wired happened. There is always a question mark at the end of that string. Please teach me the reason of it, and how to get rid of this question mark. Here is my code. Thank you so much

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Please enter a string."<<endl;
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    int i=0;
    int length = str.length();
    char arr[length];
    //cout<<length;
    while (length != 0) {
        arr[i] = str.at(length-1);
        length--;
        cout<<arr[i];
        ++i;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    string stri(arr);
    cout<<endl<<stri<<endl;
    cout<<stri[4];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `char arr[length];` is not standard C++.

Comment: You are already using a c++ `std::string` why do you bother copying it into a `char[]` just use `std::reverse`?

Comment: @Ben This is just for practice. We all started somewhere.

Comment: @Brian That makes his point is even more valid. You shouldn't practice C idioms in C++; you should practice them in C.
It is absolutely crucial for OP to learn C++ practices from the beginning, especially when they're simpler than their C alternative

Comment: I wouldn't rely on VLAs even if you intend to (which I bet this OP doesn't). I've found them to be remarkably unreliable. I feel so strongly about this that I shan't answer this question while it relies on a VLA.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Ever wondered how C++ functions (ok, let's call them methods) like `std::reverse` are implemented? Although one usually writes OO code in C++ you still need C idioms sometimes. That's why it's there. So let a new guy learn "C idioms". If it helps his understanding, then it has served its purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string in C (or many other languages) needs to be terminated by a `'\0'`. After all, you don't know how large the memory your `char*` points to is. So you need [`char[length + 1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519845/1139697). Also, [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) aren't part of C++. You need to use `new[]/delete[]` or `malloc()/free()`:

```
char * arr = new char[length + 1]; // enough space for string + '\0'
char[length] = '\0';               // terminate the string with '\0'

while (length != 0) {
    // ...                         // reverse
}
cout << endl;

string stri(arr);                  // create the new string

delete[] arr;                      // don't forget to deallocate the memory
```

However, if you're dropping down to manual memory allocation, you're usually missing something from the standard library. And indeed, you could simply use the [right constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (it's (4), simplified below):

```
template <class InputIt>
string::string(InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

And luckily, `std::string` provides input iterators that traverse the string backwards via `std::string::rbegin()` and `std::string::rend()`. Now your code gets a lot easier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a string." << std::endl;

    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Create the new reversed string directly:
    std::string reversed_string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());

    std::cout << reversed_string << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char arr[length];
```

should be

```
char arr[length + 1];
```

EDIT: or rather (as Jonathan Potter points out, since `length` is not a compile time constant, your code likely only compiles because this is permitted by your specific compiler, e.g. GNU C++):

```
char *arr = new char[length + 1];
```

(and `delete [] arr;` at some point)

to store the terminating '\0':

```
arr[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: More like "should be std::string + std::reverse". This is a C++ question after all, not C. Still upvoted because it does fix OP's problem

Comment: It shouldn't be any of these things, Andre.

Comment: We've been trying to get rid of the terrible C-style 'strings' for decades.  Now that there's a viable alternative, devs are going backwards:((