# Why do I need char[k + 1] instead of char[k] for a string with length k?

Tags: c, output

So I have a simple set of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char x[3] = "ABC"; // (*)
  puts(x);
  return 0;
}
```

It returns a strange output:

```
ABC¬ a
```

Using the top answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057309/why-is-there-a-question-mark-at-the-end-of-the-string), I found that when I change `x[3]` to `x[4]` everything runs fine.

But why? Why do I get a strange output on `x[3]`, and why is `x[4]` fine?

Comment: Because "ABC" has length 4. It's actually "ABC\0". Therefore, your string isn't terminated by zero, and `printf`'s behaviour on such strings is undefined.

Comment: You didn't declare enough space for `x`.  Remember, a string needs to be null-terminated.  Since you only declared 3 characters, the null is lost and you are printing whatever garbage happens to follow it (until you reach a null byte).

Comment: A decent compiler should have given (at least) a warning that would have made the root problem clear.  Have you disabled warnings?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Given the blue terminal color and font, I wouldn't be surprised if that's BorlandC++.

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Comment: I've tried to increase the question's quality and make it's central topic (why `char[4]` and not `char[3]`) more clear. I didn't change the actual question, but I'm not sure whether the current answers still all fit (most of them do say "you need place for the zero terminator", so it should be fine). That being said, with this title, one should be able to a) search for it and b) find a possible duplicate (there should be one, right?)

Comment: @Zeta Thank you for the question alterations! I didn't know to post that `// (*)` in identifying the problematic piece of code.

I changed the title back, though, as I recall the two hours I spent searching for my problem, the only useful searches always came when searching "something strange is happening". Also, there are indeed many duplicates to this question, though they all come in the format "Strange 'this' at the end of my string" or "Strange 'that' at the end of my string". 
No one asking the questions seemed to even consider the answer lying with x[k+1] as opposed to x[k].

Comment: Also, my question was severely downvoted after the title change of "why x[k+1] instead of x[k]?". How concerned should I be about that?

Comment: @MarkPuchalaII It was already at -2 before I've changed the title. That's why I've changed it and tried to increase the quality (to stop the downvotes and make it reproducible). Note that if `3 -> 4` is the only answer one can give, your question is too localized. That's why I tried to make it a little bit more general.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks for the input. I've changed the title back to your original revision, then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there a question mark at the end of the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057309/why-is-there-a-question-mark-at-the-end-of-the-string)

Comment: As stated in the answer to the question you linked, it's "to store the terminating `'\0'`."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You're right about the possible duplicate; the reason I posted this question was that all other versions didn't ask the specific details That confused me the most, let alone get them answered. Is there a better way to handle this than simply asking in my own words?

Comment: @MarkPuchalaII: You don't have enough reputation for it (yet), but you [can place a bounty on a question to increase awareness](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) (75 rep needed). By the way, the other answer didn't really cover how to do it in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've asked "why" this yields `ABC -a`, here's an explanation: your `char x[3] = "ABC"` isn't well suited for `puts`. `puts` expects a string terminated by zero. However, your `x` is basically:

```
char x[3] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
```

As you know, there's no way to get the length of a (dynamic) array:

```
char * allocate(){
   return malloc(rand() + 1);
}

char * mem = allocate(); // how large is mem??
```

There's no way for you to know how long it is. However, to print a string which is nothing else than a continuous sequence of characters in memory, a function needs to know when the string (aka the character sequence) ends.

That's why the [American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and many other character sets contain the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). It's basically `char` with value `0`:

```
char wrong_abc[3]   = {'A', 'B', 'C'};     // when does it end?
char correct_abc[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 0 }; // oh, there's a zero!
```

Now functions like `puts` can simply check for `0`:

```
// Simplified, actual "puts" checks for errors and returns
// EOF on error or a non-negative int on succes.
void puts(const char * str){
   int i = 0;

   while(str[i] != 0){
      putchar(str[i]);
      i++;
   }

   putchar('\n');
}
```

And that's why you

- need memory for all characters in the character sequence +1,
- get undefined behaviour when you forget the `0`.

The implementation of `puts` above would never find `0` and accidentally leave the memory you own (or access other data), which usually leads to a segfault or other errors (or worse, doesn't get detected for a long time and then yields critical errors). The actual behaviour in such a situation is undefined.

Note that string literals (e.g. `"ABC"`) automatically have a `'\0'` at the end. Also, the compiler is smart enough to figure the length of the literal for you, so you can simply use

```
char x[] = "ABC";
```

That way, you don't have to worry if you change the literal later.

Comment: I'm afraid your explanation is a bit confusing, especially the pseudo code for `printf()` `;-)`

Comment: @Zeta: Why not write an actual simplistic implementation of `puts` for illustration?  Even if the C library version is *smarter*, it should be semantically equivalent, especially regarding null termination.

Comment: @chqrlie: Fair enough. After all, it was almost already there, except for the missing increment (yup, would never terminate on non-empty strings) and the newline. I didn't add error checking, however, since that's more or less just checking the return of `putchar` and doesn't really consider whether `str` is zero terminated.

Answer (score 7):

There is no space for the terminating `\0`. In fact I would expect compilation to fail in such case.

Try

```
char x[4] = "ABC";
```

Or, as **@Zeta** suggested, just

```
char x[] = "ABC";
```

Comment: Or, even better, `char x[] = "ABC";`. Let the compiler count the characters for you.

Comment: @FiddlingBits - One assumes that this is a small sample of the code - therefore this will not be the same

Answer (score 4):

Your string should be **terminated** with `\0`.

Use

```
char x[] = "ABC";
```

instead.

> Using the top answer from this question, I found that when I change
>   x[3] to x[4] everything runs fine.
>
> BUT WHY? What is going on that x[3] is giving such a strange output?

`puts()` keeps going until it encounters **a terminating `\0`** byte. So if you don't supply one at the end of your string, it keeps running behind your string until it finds a `\0` or **crashes**..

See [puts() description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/):

> The function begins copying from the address specified (str) **until it
>   reaches the terminating null character ('\0')**. This terminating
>   null-character is not copied to the stream.

Comment: I fount `printf()` doing the same thing as puts. Does it run the same way?

Comment: @danny_ds - unless segmentation fault occurs before it finds that elusive null character

Comment: @MarkPuchalaII - Yes, all your strings should be null-terminated.

Comment: @EdHeal - Indeed: _until it finds a \0 or crashes.._

Answer (score 4):

A string is terminated by the null character - you have not allocated space for it.

Do

```
char x[] = "ABC";
```

and let the compiler do the work for you!

Comment: This leaves me curious what do to with inputs.
Should I just say something like 'scanf(x); x[strlen(x)-1] = '\0';`?

Comment: First read the manual for `scanf` then have a buffer of the right size, so you use the correct format string so that you do not overrun the buffer

Comment: Are you referring to the GNU C Manual or should I be using another?

Comment: `scanf` is more or less standard. Use the one for the compiler that you are using

Answer (score 0):

Every time you declare a string variable, just add one more character to those you need for the ending  character `'\0'` and you 'll be fine.